# JavaScript - delay a set of setTimeout activities

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a set of objects to be displayed at different times using setTimeout() function in JavaScript. What I did was to have a loop running, for every element I initialized a setTimeout event for itself.

The code I used to setTimeout for each element:

```
for (i = currentIndex; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    var object = "element#"+i;
    var delay = 10*i;
    this.keepDelay[id] = new Timer(function() {
                                $("#objectSet").css("display", "none").html(object).fadeIn("fast");
                                currentIndex = id;
                            }, delay);
}
```

The Timer class is

```
function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    // works
    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };

    // works    
    this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        id = currentIndex;
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };

    // does NOT work
    this.speedup = function() {
        remaining -= 100;
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    }

    // does NOT work
    this.slowdown = function() {
        remaining += 100;
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    }

    this.resume();
}
```

The `resume()` and `pause()` methods do work. `resume()` attempts to display each object one after another depending on the delay value. `pause()` is self-explanatory. These two are working fine.

Now I want to speed up and slow down the delay of the objects, I try to write speedup() and slowdown() methods but somehow they wouldn't work.

Looking at the code I can't find why it wouldn't, maybe I've focused on it for too long so I need to seek help from a fresh mind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: how is those functions used

Comment: You can't just operate on remaining to speed up or slow down.  You have to calculate how much time has elapsed since the timer was started and work from there.

Comment: @jfriend00 I still can't catch your point, can you explain it further more?

Comment: @user3583721 - I wrote an example of how to do it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the time that has already elapsed so you can figure out how much to set a new timer for.  Here's an example for `.speedup()`:

```
this.speedup = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    var elapsed = new Date() - start;
    remaining-= elapsed + 100;
    if (remaining > 0) {
        this.resume();
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

You would do something similar for `.slowdown()`.

---

It occurs to me this could be done a little simpler:

```
this.speedup = function() {
    this.pause();
    remaining-= 100;
    this.resume();
}

this.slowdown = function() {
    this.pause();
    remaining+= 100;
    this.resume();
}
```

and, then you change `this.resume()` to this to make sure `remaining` doesn't go negative:

```
this.resume = function() {
    start = new Date();
    id = currentIndex;
    if (remaining > 0) {
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    } else {
        callback();
    }
};
```

Comment: @user3583721 - I added a little simpler version.